# AWS SAM with !ImportValue and !Ref cannot use together

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have a Lambda function to deploy using AWS SAM. In some way, I cannot build stack if I set up layers using `!ImportValue` and `!Ref` together. If I comment one of them, it builds without errors.

```
Parameters:
  LoggingLayerARN:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /some/parameter
   
TestLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Layers:
        - !ImportValue AnotherStackLayer
        - !Ref SSMParameterLayerARN
```

The error I've got:

```
Layer References need to be of type 'AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion' or 'AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion'
```